# Selecting all strings in a list that contain a given expression in R

Tags: r, regex, text, data-analysis

I am reading a crime statistic .csv file into a variable called `crimes`. New data frame crimes contains a column titled `Text_General_Code` that briefly describes the crime that was committed. I want to find out what is the percentage of burglaries and robberies in crimes committed. I am using the following expression to calculate the percentage:

```
percentage <- (sum(str_detect(crimes$Text_General_Code, "burglary")) + sum(str_detect(crimes$Text_General_Code, "robbery")))/length(crimes$Text_General_Code)
```

I was pretty sure I am doing everything OK, but percentage always comes out as 0, which is not the case if you take a look in the .csv file. I am unsure about what could be the mistake, maybe the regular expression I am using?

Sample of .csv input
[1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGcyq.png)

[2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Og9v.png)

`dput(crimes[1:10],)` result:

```
structure(list(Dc_Dist = c(15L, 16L, 17L, 16L, 25L, 17L, 8L, 
24L, 2L, 19L), Psa = c("1", "F", "L", "F", "G", "Q", "N", "2", 
"D", "2"), Year = c("2011", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2008", "2006", 
"2009", "2015", "2007", "2014"), Month = c("05", "08", "10", 
"06", "02", "12", "06", "09", "07", "05"), Day = c("15", "22", 
"23", "01", "14", "30", "04", "29", "31", "24"), Hour = c("16", 
"00", "06", "07", "10", "12", "15", "16", "23", "23"), Minute = c("58", 
"18", "50", "34", "39", "59", "23", "27", "09", "05"), Second = c("00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00"), `-` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    Dc_Key = c(201115048144, 200616039763, 200617055978, 200616024616, 
    200825015369, 200617067285, 200908024218, 201524093777, 200702051812, 
    201419045553), Location_Block = c("4300 BLOCK CLOUD ST", 
    "3800 BLOCK SPRING GARDEN ST", "1600 BLOCK S MARSTON ST", 
    "600 BLOCK N 39TH ST  / 3900 WALLACE ST", "2800 BLOCK N HOWARD ST", 
    "1200 BLOCK S 28TH ST", "9200 BLOCK ASHTON RD", "3000 BLOCK ELLA ST", 
    "7700 BLOCK CASTOR AV", "200 BLOCK N 59TH ST"), UCR_General = c(1400L, 
    2600L, 2600L, 600L, 700L, 700L, 400L, 1800L, 2600L, 2600L
    ), Text_General_Code = c("Vandalism/Criminal Mischief", "All Other Offenses", 
    "All Other Offenses", "Thefts", "Recovered Stolen Motor Vehicle", 
    "Motor Vehicle Theft", "Aggravated Assault No Firearm", "Narcotic / Drug Law Violations", 
    "All Other Offenses", "All Other Offenses"), Police_Districts = c(11L, 
    12L, 13L, NA, 18L, 13L, 7L, 17L, 2L, 15L), Lon = c(-75.085466, 
    -75.197275, -75.190926, NA, -75.131325, -75.190218, -75.020848, 
    -75.127396, -75.060318, -75.238174), Lat = c(40.010122, 39.962331, 
    39.932177, NA, 39.993706, 39.937967, 40.064338, 39.995156, 
    40.057514, 39.964831)), .Names = c("Dc_Dist", "Psa", "Year", 
"Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "-", "Dc_Key", "Location_Block", 
"UCR_General", "Text_General_Code", "Police_Districts", "Lon", 
"Lat"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please make your question reproducible by adding some sample date (using `dput`). Also, you are not actually calculating a percentage, you are just dividing the sum by 100...

Comment: now you have added images, we can not work with images, we can only look at them.

Comment: write `dput(crimes[1:10,])` into R console, copy the result here.

Comment: Yeah I was reluctant to upload the whole dput export, but 10 lines should do

Comment: This doesn't look like it is formatted good, looks bothersome to read

Comment: `percentage <- (sum(str_detect(crimes$Text_General_Code, "(?i)burglary")) + sum(str_detect(crimes$Text_General_Code, "(?i)robbery")))/length(crimes$Text_General_Code)` works?

Comment: It does, thank you very much! Could you explain the logic behind the change that you've made?

Comment: Can robbery and burglary appear in the same row?

Comment: The sample itself doesn't contain any positive cases, but judjing by the format, there may be capital letters in your string. I suggest using `grepl` with `ignore.case=TRUE`

Comment: @Mr.T was thinking the same thing.

Comment: @JakovSergo if this solved your issue, mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

regex is case sensitive by default:

```
percentage <- (sum(str_detect(crimes$Text_General_Code, "(?i)burglary")) + sum(str_detect(crimes$Text_General_Code, "(?i)robbery")))/length(crimes$Text_General_Code)
```

use the global flag `"(?i)"` to make your search case insensitive, so that your

pattern = `"aaaa"` can match `"AaAa", "Aaaa", "aaAa" .... etc`